# JMS redelivery delay like Fibonacci number

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, jms-topic

I would like to set redelivery policy like Fibonacci number on jms topic. for example redelivery delly like below:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 ...
```

Is there any standard config on jms for this?

Answer (score 1):

JMS is just a API specification, and no there's nothing in there like that.  The messaging broker you use would be the one to examine to determine if the client and broker offer configuration for how they manage redelivery delays and if they offer such a feature or if they allow you to plug in your own delay mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

You can set delivery delay on the producer, read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms2messaging-1954190.html

Obviously there's nothing that does exactly what he asked for. He'd have to keep track of how many times he sees a message (which could be a part of the message) to set the correct delay